# Jquery noUiSlider changing steps to feet (ft)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this slider https://refreshless.com/nouislider

The slider works in steps of 10 rather than 12 for feet.

I've got the right code for making it work but there are a few errors.

Here's where I'm working on it: https://cbdoil.co.uk/cbd-calculator/

```
        <script>(function() {
    rangeslider_1.noUiSlider.on('slide', function() {
            var currentValue = mySlider.noUiSlider.get();
            $("#rangeslider_1_display").html(toInches(currentValue));
    });

    function toInches(n) {
        return Math.floor(n / 12) + "'" + (n % 12) + '"';
    }
})();</script>
```

Comment: Can't you just set the `step` to 12?

Comment: The step is 1, but when it gets to 10 it counts 4 instead of 3.11